# Specify the cuda architecture by using cmake for cuda compilation

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, cuda, cmakelists-options

I have the following cmake and cuda code for generating a 750 cuda arch, however, this always results in a **CUDA_ARCH** = 300 (2080 ti with cuda 10.1). I tried both `set_property` and `target_compile_options`, which all failed. Do we have a solution for both `cuda_add_executable` and  `cuda_add_library` in this case to make the `-gencode` part effective？

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(Hello)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
cuda_add_executable(oounne ttt.cu)
set_property(TARGET oounne PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75)
#target_compile_options(oounne PRIVATE  $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:-gencode 
arch=compute_75,code=sm_75>)
```

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#define STR_HELPER(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_HELPER(x)

__device__ void print_arch(){
  const char my_compile_time_arch[] = STR(__CUDA_ARCH__);
  printf("__CUDA_ARCH__: %s\n", my_compile_time_arch);
}
__global__ void example()
{
   print_arch();
}

int main(){

example<<<1,1>>>();
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Comment: Try this:  
`project(Hello CUDA)`
`enable_language(CUDA)`
`set_property(TARGET oounne PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75)`

Comment: This works well, thanks

Comment: @kjpus if you want to provide an answer I would upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change my comment to an answer:

```
project(Hello CUDA) 
enable_language(CUDA) 
set_property(TARGET oounne PROPERTY CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 75)
```